# How can I made custom taxonomies relationship?

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-taxonomy, filters

I create two custom taxonomies:

- **Category** (Cars, Pets etc).
- **Region** (New York, Washington etc).

Now I need to do archives like `{Category}` in `{Region}` (for ex. **Cars** in **New York**) and get slugs for it (`mysite.com/ads/cars/nyc` or `mysite.com/ads/cars/?city=New+York`).
How can I set such dependency?

I got only one idea - using subcategories (for ex. Cars is parent, New York is child) but think it's not good solution.

Nice solution has WooCommerce with its filters (attributes), but I don't know how it works.

Comment: please check this link  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50068918/relationship-between-2-custom-posts-in-wp